# Is there any hope of getting a jQuery object representing the DOM contents of an Ember view that doesn't add its own tag?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to use this.$() in the some event functions for my Ember views (such as didInsertElement) to give me access to the actual DOM stuff that a view adds to the page.  Sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't.  I want it to work always.  After delving into ember.js somewhat, I think I've learned that it fails, particularly, for a view that doesn't happen to add its own div (or any other tag) to the DOM to wrap the other DOM elements it adds.  This seems to be a normal format for the div tag:

```
<div id="ember208" class="ember-view">
</div>
```

In this case, I think "ember208" is the value of the view's "elementId" field; and it appears that this.$() uses "elementId" to try to look up a single tag with that ID.

For some views, there is no such tag.  For instance, if I make a route called "whatever" but don't define a WhateverView, then I don't seem to get that special div around the rendered contents of the "whatever" template.  Also, implicit views seem to crop up at other times...  I think the contents of an #if block may get their own view?  Anyhow, it's clear that didInsertElement code often runs, for me, with an empty this.$().

I am seeing this especially often because I've hooked up code to didInsertElement via View.reopen():

```
Ember.View.reopen(
{
  uhhh: function()
  {
    console.log("add " + this.$().length);
  }.on("didInsertElement"),

  hmm: function()
  {
    console.log("del " + this.$().length);
  }.on("willDestroyElement")
});
```

It seems I have tampered with dark magics here.  I want these functions to basically let me detect every element that Ember adds to or removes from the DOM, right after it's been added or before it's removed.*  But that length is often zero.  My perusal of the source code seems to indicate it will always be zero, except where the view gets its own wrapper tag.  I do not, in fact, want EVERY view to get its own wrapper tag.  If I want to watch Ember's changes to the DOM in this way, but without having wrapper tags for every view, then...  what do I do?

**Edit**

*Clarification:  I don't necessarily want didInsertElement to be called once for every DOM element that Ember adds.  Rather, I want the addition of any one element to have one corresponding call to didInsertElement--with many elements potentially sharing the same call.  So if Ember adds a whole template's worth of elements all at once, then one call to didInsertElement in which this.$() represents either the single newly added ancestor of all those newly added elements, or the collection of all the added elements themselves, or the collection of all their topmost newly added ancestors (if there weren't a single one), would serve me well.

Comment: Ember doesn't create a view for every element in the page.  Can you give a scenario you are attempting to accomplish so that we can see if there is another way to accomplish what you need to do?

Comment: I just checked one of my Ember pages, 7661 elements in page.

Comment: I don't want a single view for every single element.  I want every addition of elements to show up in didInsertElement, or in some other such place, and I want the new elements to be accessible in the jQuery way at that point.  So, I suppose, I was assuming that there would at least be one view per "chunk" of page that is capable of being added or removed as a unit.  My experience with Ember has seemed to at least weakly suggest that that actually is the case.

Comment: "Can you give a scenario you are attempting to accomplish so that we can see if there is another way to accomplish what you need to do?"

I've already found another way.  But in the long run, I think this could easily come up for me again.  It's potentially very nice to be able to reliably watch Ember add and remove chunks of DOM.  I want to be able to do that, even if I don't know that I absolutely need to do it.  (But if the answer is that it's just not allowed, then, oh well.  I'm not trying to say Ember is broken without this or anything.)

Comment: So almost watching when anything changes on the page, and possibly checking if something in the page (like reactive sizing)?

Comment: Is this so exotic?  I just want the interaction between didInsertElement/willDestroyElement and View.$() to work the way I understand it's supposed to.  It doesn't, for some views, because View.$() fails to do its job (according to the Ember documentation's claim about what its job is).  I suspect the Ember developers would consider that to be a bug in the documentation, not a bug in the code; but even so, that's what I want.

Comment: lol, I wasn't claiming it to be extreme, it was a sincere question ;)  Can you show an example where this.$() isn't working?

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vozoguna/15/edit Click back and forth between the two routes, and you'll see a lot of zeroes.  Uncomment the Dealie.ThingView line and some of the zeroes will become ones.  But the documentation says View.$() returns "the jQuery object for the DOM node"--ONE jQuery object, not zero.

Comment: It looks related to the fact that `reopen`ing the View class isn't supported only extending it.  So on the reopen'd versions it's triggering from the core view, and also collection view, but not on the view itself.  I'd just create a base view and extend all of your views from it, which appears to work.

Comment: But then I still don't see a way to listen for the insertion and removal of hiDiv in my example (a div in an #if block).  I'd rather have didInsertElement get called for that div with an empty this.$() than get no call at all.

Comment: Correct, you'd need to use render or a view itself inside if you needed to know when that particular group was inserted into the dom.